# final can be used to define class

Tags: java

here 
1.final is used in class ,so it must be not modifiable.so anyone plz explain.
and 
2.copy constructor is allowed in java?

```
final class Complex {
    private  double re,  im;
    public Complex(double re, double im) {
        this.re = re;
        this.im = im;
    }
    Complex(Complex c)
    {
        System.out.println("Copy constructor called");
        re = c.re;
        im = c.im;
    }
    public String toString() {
        return "(" + re + " + " + im + "i)";
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Complex c1 = new Complex(10, 15);
        Complex c2 = new Complex(c1);
        Complex c3 = c1;
        System.out.println(c2);
    }
}
```

Comment: `final` doesn't not mean that the class is not modifiable. It simply means that you cannot extend the class.

Answer (score 2):

The `final` keyword in reference to a class does not state that its instances cannot be modified. It only disallows subclassing it. The final keyword should be [applied to fields <sup>JLS 8.3.1.2</sup>](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.3.1.2) in order to make instances immutable.

Please see [JLS 8.1.1.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.1.2):

> A class can be declared final if its definition is complete and no subclasses are desired or required.
>
> It is a compile-time error if the name of a final class appears in the extends clause (§8.1.4) of another class declaration; this implies that a final class cannot have any subclasses.
>
> It is a compile-time error if a class is declared both final and abstract, because the implementation of such a class could never be completed (§8.1.1.1).
>
> Because a final class never has any subclasses, the methods of a final class are never overridden (§8.4.8.1).

Your copy constructor is acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

When you declare a `class` as `final` it doesn't make it immutable, instead it makes the class unable to be extendible by other classes i.e. it cannot be subclassed.

If you want to make your class immutable you should mark your fields as `final`:

```
class Complex {
    private final double re,  im;
}
```

This is noted in [Java Language Specification. 8.1.1.2. final Classes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.1.2):

> A class can be declared final if its definition is complete and no subclasses are desired or required.

Copy constructors are allowed in Java. You just made one and the compiler didn't complain about it.

Answer (score 0):

Declaring a class `final` does not make it **immutable**. It simple means that the **class cannot be extended**.

Answer (score 0):

A class that is declared as final can not be extended. Instances of that class are still mutable. See the [Oracle Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/final.html)

You are free to write your own copy constructor in Java but they are just like a normal constructor. The compiler will not generate one for you or anything.

Answer (score 0):

1- Final keyword means that a class cannot be extended anymore

2- Complex c3 = c1 is valid in Java, but both vars(c1 & c3) are pointing to the same Object.